# Show that the action of PSL$_2(\mathbb Z)$ on a quadratic form by $g \cdot Q = Q(ax + by, cx + dy)$ preserves the set of properly represented numbers

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, mobius-transformation

I am trying to show that

> the action of PSL$_2(\mathbb Z)$ on a quadratic form by $g \cdot Q = Q(ax + by, cx + dy)$ preserves the set of properly represented numbers, where
> $$g = \begin{pmatrix}
>         a & b \\
>         c & d
>     \end{pmatrix}.$$

Clearly $g$ is a Mobius transformation.

I have already proved that this action is a right action $(g \circ(h \circ Q)) = (gh) \circ Q)$ and that it preserves the discriminant of $Q$.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? My current idea is to use the fact that the smallest three values a reduced BQF will give are $A$, $C$, and $A + C - |B|$. If two BQFs both have these as their smallest three, they must properly represent the same numbers.

Comment: "properly represented numbers" ?